# Error trapping combined with a counter not working

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, try-except

I'm making a code that makes a user enter RLE line by line. I then send the entered data to a function that decodes it. Within the function, I've included some basic error trapping.

My error is that when the user can only enter incorrect data the number of times they choose (they choose the amount of lines they want to enter). i.e. if the user enters 2 (out of 3) correct lines of RLE and then enters an incorrect line, the code won't ask to enter the RLE again, but if they enter an incorrect line at the first or second input it works.

Code:

```py
if line_amount>2:
            print ("Please enter the compressed data one line at a time")
            while line_amount > counter:
                compressed_data = input('->') #ENTER RLE DATA
                counter+=1
                RLEtoASCII(compressed_data,counter)
```

RLEtoASCII:

```py
def RLEtoASCII(compressed_data,counter):
    try:
        pairs = [(int(compressed_data[i:i+2]), compressed_data[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(compressed_data), 3)]
        global text
        text = ''.join(n * c for n, c in pairs)
        RLE_Inputs = open("Entered Data.txt", 'a+') #File that lists all the inputs
        #[etc all the file writing]
    except:
        print('THERE WAS A PROBLEM WITH THE VALUES Please re-enter values.\n')
```

If I try calling `RLEtoASCII` after the except, it creates a loop. `counter -=1` doesn't appear to work after the except either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the error handling out of your function and into the if loop, we can more easily control the iteration:

```
if line_amount>2:
            print ("Please enter the compressed data one line at a time")
            while line_amount > counter:
                compressed_data = input('->') #ENTER RLE DATA
                if compressed_data != '':
                    try:
                        RLEtoASCII(compressed_data)
                        counter+=1
                    except:
                        print('THERE WAS A PROBLEM WITH THE VALUES Please re-enter values.\n')
```

RLEtoASCII:

```
def RLEtoASCII(compressed_data):
    pairs = [(int(compressed_data[i:i+2]), compressed_data[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(compressed_data), 3)]
    global text
    text = ''.join(n * c for n, c in pairs)
    RLE_Inputs = open("Entered Data.txt", 'a+') #File that lists all the inputs
    #[etc all the file writing]
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the problem! Thanks so much! (Sorry for my ignorance lol...)

Comment: No worries! And it's okay you weren't ignorant, we all make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `>` in `while line_amount > counter:` to `>=`. This is because when you get to the third line it is testing for if 3>3 which is false, while 3>=3 is true.

Comment: That only pushes the error off. Then, if an incorrect input is made at input#2 you'll have two more chances but that's it, it wont ask you over and over again until you get three correct inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `counter` is incremented even when you catch an error. I changed counter to a global so that it effectively is't incremented when there is an error. just make sure you put `global counter` above your definition. Let me know if this works for you.

```
if line_amount>2:
            print ("Please enter the compressed data one line at a time")
            while line_amount > counter:
                compressed_data = input('->') #ENTER RLE DATA
                counter+=1
                RLEtoASCII(compressed_data)
```

RLEtoASCII:

```
def RLEtoASCII(compressed_data):
    global counter
    try:
        pairs = [(int(compressed_data[i:i+2]), compressed_data[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(compressed_data), 3)]
        global text
        text = ''.join(n * c for n, c in pairs)
        RLE_Inputs = open("Entered Data.txt", 'a+') #File that lists all the inputs
        #[etc all the file writing]
    except:
        print('THERE WAS A PROBLEM WITH THE VALUES Please re-enter values.\n')
        counter-=1
```

Comment: Would `def option_1(counter):` affect it? Because it seems to as the code isn't working... (I'm not the best with global and locals)

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean. A global variable is one that can be used across all functions, which is why when you tried `counter -=1` as stated in your question it didn't work. a local variable is a variable that can't be called outside the function it is defined in. an example here is the variable `pairs`

Comment: This isn't actually a very good solution, I'll post another answer that works better and doesn't require a global.